# Why does the size of this Python String change on a failed int conversion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, python-internals

From the [tweet here](https://twitter.com/dabeaz/status/925787482515533830):

```
import sys
x = 'ñ'
print(sys.getsizeof(x))
int(x) #throws an error
print(sys.getsizeof(x))
```

We get 74, then 77 bytes for the two `getsizeof` calls.

It looks like we are adding 3 bytes to the object, from the failed int call.

Some more examples from twitter (you may need to restart python to reset the size back to 74):

```
x = 'ñ'
y = 'ñ'
int(x)
print(sys.getsizeof(y))
```

77!

```
print(sys.getsizeof('ñ'))
int('ñ')
print(sys.getsizeof('ñ'))
```

74, then 77.

Comment: Must be related to PEP393 **Flexible** String Representation.

Comment: Before even clicking on the tweet link I *knew* it was Beazley who tweeted it.

Comment: yeap, it's looking increasingly likely I'm going to have to save up and go to one of his courses

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The code that converts strings to ints in CPython 3.6 [requests a UTF-8 form of the string to work with](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/longobject.c#L2503):

```
buffer = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(asciidig, &buflen);
```

and the string creates the UTF-8 representation the first time it's requested and [caches it on the string object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L4016):

```
if (PyUnicode_UTF8(unicode) == NULL) {
    assert(!PyUnicode_IS_COMPACT_ASCII(unicode));
    bytes = _PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(unicode, NULL);
    if (bytes == NULL)
        return NULL;
    _PyUnicode_UTF8(unicode) = PyObject_MALLOC(PyBytes_GET_SIZE(bytes) + 1);
    if (_PyUnicode_UTF8(unicode) == NULL) {
        PyErr_NoMemory();
        Py_DECREF(bytes);
        return NULL;
    }
    _PyUnicode_UTF8_LENGTH(unicode) = PyBytes_GET_SIZE(bytes);
    memcpy(_PyUnicode_UTF8(unicode),
              PyBytes_AS_STRING(bytes),
              _PyUnicode_UTF8_LENGTH(unicode) + 1);
    Py_DECREF(bytes);
}
```

The extra 3 bytes are for the UTF-8 representation.

---

You might be wondering why the size doesn't change when the string is something like `'40'` or `'plain ascii text'`. That's because if the string is in ["compact ascii" representation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Include/unicodeobject.h#L202), Python doesn't create a separate UTF-8 representation. It [returns the ASCII representation directly](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L80), which is already valid UTF-8:

```
#define PyUnicode_UTF8(op)                              \
    (assert(_PyUnicode_CHECK(op)),                      \
     assert(PyUnicode_IS_READY(op)),                    \
     PyUnicode_IS_COMPACT_ASCII(op) ?                   \
         ((char*)((PyASCIIObject*)(op) + 1)) :          \
         _PyUnicode_UTF8(op))
```

---

You also might wonder why the size doesn't change for something like `'１'`. That's U+FF11 FULLWIDTH DIGIT ONE, which `int` treats as equivalent to `'1'`. That's because [one of the earlier steps](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/longobject.c#L2500) in the string-to-int process is

```
asciidig = _PyUnicode_TransformDecimalAndSpaceToASCII(u);
```

which converts all whitespace characters to `' '` and converts all Unicode decimal digits to the corresponding ASCII digits. This conversion returns the original string if it doesn't end up changing anything, but when it does make changes, it creates a new string, and the new string is the one that gets a UTF-8 representation created.

---

As for the cases where calling `int` on one string looks like it affects another, those are actually the same string object. There are many conditions under which Python will reuse strings, all just as firmly in Weird Implementation Detail Land as everything we've discussed so far. For `'ñ'`, the reuse happens because this is a single-character string in the Latin-1 range (`'\x00'`-`'\xff'`), and the implementation [stores and reuses those](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L213).

Comment: @jeremycg: Your snippet never requests the UTF-8. String concatenation doesn't perform a UTF-8 conversion.

Comment: That's great work, but to me it's a little hard to understand why the error produced for int('ñ') produces a carry of 3, and not the error of int('[') for example. what's diference?

Comment: Ok, and I guess we also hold the 'ñ' in memory, and modify that, rather than a copy, also explaining the x/y one, and the 'ñ','ñ' one. I Think this is it, but will hold off accepting to see if there's any other ideas.

Comment: @DamianLattenero: My answer now addresses that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, now I understand it! Great answer